# Apple sign in with watch os simulator

Tags: watchos, apple-sign-in

Whenever I try to tap on apple sign in button in Apple watch Series 5 simulator, it asks me to go and update passcode in settings. Even after updating the passcode many times, still the sign in functionality is not working. I had written the following code for authorization:

I had used `ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider` for creating request for authorization.

```
let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
            let request = appleIDProvider.createRequest()
            request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]

            let authorizationController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
            authorizationController.delegate = self
            authorizationController.performRequests()
```

Since the process is not completed so every time I am getting error:

```
 func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithError error: Error)
```

The error:

> [core] Authorization failed: Error Domain=AKAuthenticationError
> Code=-7080 "(null)"